# Seeking above ground biomass global map/dataset?

Tags: raster, data, asia

I need a global above-ground biomass raster dataset from which I will subset a certain area of southeast Asia. I tried to use GEDI data but couldn't work out how to use this data.

Is there any other data set that will serve this purpose or can you point out how I can use GEDI AGB data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dataset could work for you -> https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NASA_ORNL_biomass_carbon_density_v1